# What is the word between the first and last name called?

Tags: translation, names

In German, and other languages, it is common to have a word between your first and last name.

For example, a typical Dutch name would be:
"Jan de Vries". Where "Vries" is the last name and "Jan" the first name.

"Charles de Gaulle" is a French example.

What would I call "de" in this case?

Comment: From what I have heard, *de* is just a preposition to a toponymic surname. If the surname is *Vries*, then *de Vries* is like, *from Vries*.

Comment: In French at least, the "de" in front of a last name is part of the last name, so it should stay the same in English (e.g.: Charles de Gaulle - French president during WW2).

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan Actually, that would be _van_, as in _Jeroen van Velzen_. _De_ is the definite article and is also often used to indicate a person's origin (_de Vries_ would roughly translate as _the Frisian_, similarly _den Hollander_ would be _the Dutchman_) but also to indicate professions (_de Smid_, _(the) Smith) or other properties ( _de Lange_, _the Tall_).

Comment: Additionally, in _de Vries_, the surname is not _Vries_. The whole _de Vries_ is considered the surname. In Belgium (contrary to the Netherlands), the middle part is even used in alphabetical ordering, so _de Vries_ would be found near _Vrijlandt_, whereas _Vries_ would be ordered near _Van Velzen_.

Comment: "de" , "von" or "della" are [nobiliary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle). But, they are not always a sign of nobility.

Comment: *What's Tony the Tiger's middle name?* In most Western societies, the surname is usually shared between members of the same family. If Tony the Tiger's father was Tom the Tiger, I'd suggest that their shared last name is "the Tiger" (and the first name is simply "Tony"). If it was Tom Stripy Tiger, you could assume that "Tony the" were the given (first) names, or first name and middle name.

Comment: Surprisingly, the English Wikipedia has a 'tussenvoegsel' lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussenvoegsel

Comment: In the US we generally consider "van", "von", "de", et al, to be part of the "last name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Graffito** pointed a possible the answer when he mentioned the [nobiliary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle):

> A nobiliary particle is used in a surname or family name in many Western cultures to signal the nobility of a family.

However, the mentioned *de*, as well as the common Dutch *van* are **not** signs of nobility (contrary to the German *Von*). However, the wikipedia article continues:

> However, in some languages the nobiliary particle is the same as a regular **prepositional particle** that was used in the creation of many surnames.

So it seems that at least grammatically we can refer to it as a *prepositional particle*, used in the same way as a *nobiliary particle*.

Of course, I *doubt* anyone would know what to fill in on a form if you use *prepositional particle* as a descriptor of a name field...

---

As far as usage is concerned, the prepositional particle is considered part of the surname. So *Jan de Vries* has the surname *de Vries*, not *Vries*. In Belgium, the prepositional particle is even used when ordering names alphabetically.

Comment: This answer could benefit from incorporating your comment, that in English generally *"in de Vries, the surname is not Vries. The whole de Vries is considered the surname"*. I'd suggest two sections to this answer: 1. Grammatical answer (what you already have). 2. Practical answer (your quoted comment). [ I felt this was too big an edit to make myself without permission.]

Comment: I like that you considered the usage of this in a form, which was indeed my initial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If we agree *de* is part of the surname rather than a separator between first and last name, perhaps it is simply a **Surname prefix**

Looking at [Wikipedia for Celtic Onomastics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_onomastics#Surname_prefixes%20says) (and I think same principle applies to Celtic/Dutch/German/etc), it calls these *Surname Prefixes*, as follows ...

> **Surname prefixes**
> [...]
>
> **De**: "of the": a Norman-French habitational prefix used by some of the most common Irish surnames among which are De Búrca, Le Brún, De Barra, De Cíosóg, Devane and de Faoite. 'De' historically has signaled ownership of lands and was traditionally therefore a mark of prestige.
>
> **Mac**: for most purposes, taken to mean "son of", as in Mac Néill (son of Neil).